# ListView - > Displaying data through coding

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I want to retrieve the recipe names from the database and need to display the data in the list form. I have added the code behind. But what do I include in the template.

Source

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
                    <ItemTemplate>

                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:ListView>
```

Code behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=FreedomKitchen;Uid=root;Password=;");
    con.Open();
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select Recipe_Name from Recipes", con);
    MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter();
    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "Recipe_Names");
    ListView1.DataSource = ds;
    ListView1.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add a label if you want to display only data 
'>

or textbox if you want to edit the data

Comment: Hi, I need want the list item to be like a link to the next page, which will show a detailed view of the recipe. So which is a desirable implementation? Would button work? How can I implement on item listener on this...? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add ASP.NET controls in the template and then use the [`Eval`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.databinder.eval(v=vs.110).aspx) method to [bind](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/presenting-and-managing-data/model-binding/retrieving-data) to the value of a field from your dataset:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="recipe_name" 
                   runat="Server" 
                   <!-- in eval you use the name of a field/property 
                        found in your collection or datatable    
                   -->
                   Text='<%#Eval("Recipe_Name") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

You can find the documentation for itemtemplates on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.itemtemplate(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can put in the `<ItemTemplate>` whatever you want to display in the specific list view item.

In addition, I think it will be easier for you to map `DataSet` into appropriate collection of *Recipe* type.

For example, in the designer:

```
<ItemTemplate>
   <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl"></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Code Behind:

```
void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    ...Code...
    ListView1.ItemDataBound += new EventHandler<System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewItemEventArgs>(ListView1_ItemDataBound);
}

private void ListView1_ItemDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {
        var recipeName = e.Item.DataItem as *Your_Recipe_Class_Type*;
        if (recipeName != null)
        {
            Label lbl = e.Item.FindControl("lbl");
            lbl.Text = recipeName.*DesiredProperty*;
        }
    }
}
```